# How to manually change Locale in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm kind of new to flutter development and I've hit a big wall with the issue of making the app "international".

For this project, it's supposed to be available in 3 languages including english. So I've followed the flutter tutorial [available here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization). I wrote 3 `.arb` files, and everything works with the phone's language. Now I'm supposed to create a button in the settings page that allows me to manually switch language.

And that's where I'm stuck. I've found many tutorials from different pages, all different, none of them I was able to make work. I've defined globale `Locales` and I've tried to call `AndroidLocalizationDelegate.load(myLocaleEN)` to no avail.

Any help is appreciated, I'm really lost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `MaterialApp` / `CupertinoApp` / `WidgetsApp` then you can just pass your current locale with the `locale` parameter.

So you can treat your locale as any other state in the app – change it on button press, store it in shared preferences, etc.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of something so simple, thanks so much!